# How to change the secondary route in Angular?

Tags: angular, routes

This is my **app.routing.module.ts** file

```
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'driverregister',outlet: 'adminnavbar', component: RegisterdriverComponent},
      { path: 'viewdrivers',outlet: 'adminnavbar', component: ViewdriversComponent},
      { path: 'editdriverdetails',outlet: 'adminnavbar', component: EditdriverdetailsComponent},
    ]
  },
```

After clicking the following router link

`[routerLink]="[{outlets: {'adminnavbar': 'driverregister'}}]"`

my URL is showing as

`http://localhost:4200/admin/(adminnavbar:viewdrivers)`

Now I want to change my URL to

`http://localhost:4200/admin/(adminnavbar:editdriverdetails)`

I tried using

`[routerLink]="[{outlets: {'adminnavbar': 'editdriverdetails'}}]"`

but it didn't worked. It shows the following error in the console.

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin'`

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you go to your RouterModule.forRoot and add the following `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })` and see what route is actually being requested?

Comment: `"/admin/(adminnavbar:viewdrivers/(adminnavbar:editdriverdetails))"` will be shown as the new route

Comment: Do you have to use multiple router outlets? If you do, have you tried, `[routerLink]="['/admin', {outlets: {'adminnavbar': 'editdriverdetails'}}]"`

Comment: It worked. Thank you!!!

Comment: Excellent! Let me put it into an answer that explains for future generations :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information in `[routerLink]` is an array of commands. By default, routerLink is relative to your current route. If you are already on `http://localhost:4200/admin/(adminnavbar:viewdrivers)`, then when you use the `[routerLink]="[{outlets: {'adminnavbar': 'editdriverdetails'}}]"`, Angular will use the current route as the base route. What you are wanting is to go back to the base route of `admin`.

It should look like this `[routerLink]="['/admin', {outlets: {'adminnavbar': 'editdriverdetails'}}]"`. This says,

1. First go to the `/admin` route
2. Then go to the `(adminnavbar:viewdrivers)` outlet